# Create Named Shared Memory files to transfer huge data

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-mapped-files

Using MSDN's example on [Creating Named Shared Memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx), I have some questions (note: variable names inline are referred from the example process 1 in hyperlink):

- Would it be possible to copy high length messages (ie. szMsg.length() > 4000) to buffer (pBuf) in process 1?
- What is the max size of the buffer (BUF_SIZE) allowed for creating file mapping object?
- If yes, what is the relation between buffer size used for creating mapping object vs length of the message.(ie.. In the example, BUF_SIZE vs szMsg)

I am asking these questions because when I try to copy messages of length > 4000, it fails with access violation errors, in spite of increasing `buf_size` from 512 to 1024 or even higher.

I am new to coding. Kindly explain to me how to create a file mapping object which could accommodate high length messages.

Comment: Yes it is possible to use memory mapped files of size 4000 bytes. In fact that is not huge at all. If you can do it for a single byte you can do it for 4000 just by increasing the size. It is trivial. Your code is surely defective in some way. Are are aware that 1024 is less than 4000? Do you appreciate that a buffer must be at least as big as its content? Why are you using memory mapping anyway.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I understand that 4000>1024. But I observed that this buffer size is not directly proportional to message length. Even if I put buffer size as 8 and I could successfully copy message up to length ~4000.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I am suppose to send some data which is being processed in Main thread to another concurrent process

Comment: Or for heaven's sake. You overrun the buffer and anything could happen. Including the code appearing to work. Why on earth are you doing it wrong on purpose. Just allocate a buffer of sufficient size and stop wasting our time. You've been asking about this for days now. If you want to send some data to another process it is usually better to use IPC other than mapped files. Pipes. Sockets. Messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you write to more than `BUF_SIZE` bytes, Windows does not guarantee what happens.  In practise though, the file-mapping will be rounded up to a memory page (which happens to be 4096).  Thus if you specify a "small" value for `BUF_SIZE`, you will get away with messages upto and including 4096 bytes long - but if you write 4097 bytes, you <strike>will</strike> will probably(*) get an access violation.

*: If you are unlucky, the next page will already be mapped into the process, and you will overwrite some other critical information.

Solution: You must set `BUF_SIZE` to be at least as large as the largest message you want to send.

> What is the relation between buffer size used for creating mapping
>   object vs length of the message.(ie.. In the example, `BUF_SIZE` vs
>   `szMsg`)

A: `BUFSIZE` must be greater than or equal to `szMsg`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Excellent point!

Comment: @MartinBonner. Thanq very much for your answer. But in my code i'am getting the message length of 6200 bytes. I kept the buffer of size 8192. Even then it failed. What could be other probabilities of failure.

Comment: @MartinBonner: What is the maximum size of the memory page allowed (buffer size)?  IF it exceeds how should it be handled ? For time being am splitting the string of length 4000 and creating multiple map file objects.

Comment: In a 32-bit program you will run out of address space at just under 2Gbytes (You can squeeze this to 3Gbytes if you must).  In a 64-bit program it will depend on the amount of RAM, or the size of the page file.  I think there is an upper limit of 128TBytes in Windows 10.

Comment: Multiple maps? That's just crazy. We've told you so many times that you can have maps with sufficient size. Your code is defective. Surely you suspect your own code of being broken? And yet you keep asking the same question, keep trying to allocate under-sized buffers. And finally, memory mapping is a really poor way to send a message from one process to another. Why did you pick that technique ahead of all the others that are more suitable?

Comment: @user3852447: Please construct a [mcve] (not in particular the *Minimal* there - we don't want your whole program), and ask another question as to why you can't store a message of 6200 bytes in a buffer of size 8192.  (Possible answer: It isn't 6200 bytes - it's 6200 `wchar_t`s, which required 12400 bytes.)  (Sorry @DavidHeffernan - but that would be a genuine question.) Also, as David has been saying: Why are you using memory mapping for such trivial amounts of data?  12k bytes is not "huge", it's "small".  "Huge" would a gigabyte.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Minor correction, a 32-bit process gets to use 4GB of address space, when running on a 64-bit OS (and has the *large address aware* flag set in its PE header). The address space limits are somewhat arbitrarily picked for 64-bit versions of Windows (see [Memory Limits for Windows and Windows Server Releases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778.aspx)). Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1 do have a limit of 128TB of user-mode address space per 64-bit process, as you pointed out already.

Comment: @IInspectable: Well spotted on 4G. That was the page where I got the 128TB limit from - but it doesn't say what the Windows 10.0 limit is (I assume unchanged, it's unlikely to go down, but they'll have to increase it at some point.)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No.  I meant the 128TB limit will have to go up.